# Predict Two Variables vs Predict One Variable with Two Models

Tags: machine-learning

Is there any difference if we predict two variables vs predict one variable with two models (so we have two variables predicted)?

Comment: How are you predicting one variable with two models?

Comment: @Emre Two models that predicts one independent variables, so we are predicting two variables.

Comment: Give us the model you want to use.

Comment: I mean in general, for example a logistic classifier. What is the implication if we predicted two variable instead of one?

Comment: Logistic can only give a single prediction??

Comment: How about multinomial logistic classification?

Comment: Multinomial is not equal to multiple logistic. Two very different models. They give you different results, different assumptions.

Comment: By "predicting two variables", do you mean predicting a single dependent variable with multiple categories? Or several dummy variables, each representing a single class in your dependent variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think OP meant a *multi-class* model that predicts an outcome variable with multiple classes versus building multiple separate binary classification models for *each* class. Indeed these two modeling techniques are different, and should be used differently according to the problem.

### Multi-class Classification Problems

These are problems where you have to assign cases to a dependent variable with multiple categories/classes/outcome. Classes are mutually exclusive, meaning that observations can be assigned to only one category at a time (estimated probability for every category of $Y$ adds up to one). Many algorithms exists for this type of problem. For example Random Forest, Multinomial Logistic Regression, Boosted Trees, Linear Discriminant Analysis, etc. Each with their own set of assumptions.

In the muli-class case, multinomial logisitc regression actually picks a "pivot" class and runs a binary logistic regression for each class regressing on the pivot class.

### Multi-label Classification Problems

These are problems where each case can be assigned to more than one category. The dependent variable is still multi-class, but we cannot use a multi-class classification model because the categories are *not* mutually exclusive. There exist several ways to deal with multi-label problems, one of which is to transform a multi-label problem to multiple distinct binary classification problems. This is known as a **binary relevance transformation**. This can be done by simply treating each class of the dependent variable as a binary outcome (in that specific class or not), and running a binary classification method (like binary logistic regression) on each of them.

This is similar to the multinomial logsitic regression case because multiple binary logistic regressions are run, but it is also different because each model in this case is independent and do not depend on a chosen pivot class.

### Multi-class or Multi-label?

To answer your question: "Multi-class to predict a multi-category dependent or several binary models to predict each class?". It really depends on your problem. Do you want to assign multiple classes to each observation? If so, you have a multi-label problem and the binary relevance transformation is a good way to model. Are categories in your dependent variable instead mutually exclusive? In this case, use multi-class classification models.

**Note:** The downside of binary relevance is that it treats each category of the dependent variable to be independent, thus ignoring any dependencies across different classes. A **label powerset transformation** is a good alternative. This transforms the dependent variable into a multi-class variable with each class representing the occurrence of a combination of the original classes. A multi-class model is then run on these new combination classes. This takes into account the *co-occurrence* of classes not just single occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify what exactly the model you're thinking. Of course there're differences. For example:

- Multiple comparisons (inflate Type 1 error)
- Loss in statistical power
- Different probability mass function
- Marginal distribution vs joint distribution

In general, we're talking about Apple and Orange. They have different interpretation, different equations, different formula, different way to estimate solution etc etc.

Comment: There are models that support multiple output variables. If we use the model with 2 outputs versus create two models with one output, what are the implications? I'm not sure if this is a good question.

Comment: @user1157751 Please tell us what model you're talking about. Please note they are most likely different in statistical assumptions. If you give a name, I'll try to edit my answer.

Comment: For example sklearn's DecisionTreeClassifier (RandomForestClassifier is built on top of this)